# How to replace the plus/minus button of Grouped UITableView in editing mode?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitableview

What i am trying to figure out is to add an UIImageView in front of the grouped UITableView while it is in editing mode, just like the ways plus/minus button behaves. There is hell a lot of footprint to build a room there if we could make use of it. 
Is there any solution or workaround? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just add a UIImageView as a subview to the table cell and give it a negative left offset to put it outside the cell frame.

The cell may clip to its bounds by default (I don't recall offhand), but if it does, just set the table cell's clipToBounds property to NO.

Comment: Nice tricks, Nick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll try it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

You must override the `UIView` method `layoutSubviews` of your table view and check for the editing state. Then you can redraw the cell to your heart's content.